# Expo & React Native Axios File Post Issues on Android - Value for uri cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap

Tags: react-native, expo

```
        const uri = await getFileInfo(fileName);
        const body = new FormData();

        body.append('file', {
            uri,
            name: 'helloworld',
            type: 'image/jpeg'
        });

        // process current image
        await axios.post(`${MEDIA_URL}/raw`, body, headers);
```

This above code works well on IOS but on Android I'm getting the following:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Value for uri cannot be cast from
>   ReadableNativeMap to String

There's no obvious indication as to where it's coming from but the URI object looks like this:

```
Object {
  "exists": true,
  "isDirectory": false,
  "modificationTime": 1560600287,
  "size": 2898352,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.project.name/files/ExperienceData/%2540project%252Fproject-name/_64_4/838f7807-bb53-4017-bd5a-f8f506292ad3.jpg",
}
```

Any indication as to what has caused this?

Comment: did you find the solution?